# In LINQPad, the results has special styling for NULL. How can I apply that to boolean values or other values?

Tags: linqpad

I would like to be able to style different return values similar to how LINQPad styles NULL as italic green text. Specifically, I would like to style Boolean values TRUE and FALSE differently like blue and red.

[image: null values are styled differently]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can't be done through the built-in stylesheet editor. However you could write an extension method that you invoke as follows:

```
void Main()
{
    // AdventureWorks
    Contacts.Select (c => new { c.FirstName, c.LastName, NameStyle = c.NameStyle.RedBlue() }).Dump();
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static object RedBlue (this bool value)
    {       
        string c = value ? "Blue" : "Red";
        return Util.RawHtml ("<span style='color:" + c + "'>" + value + "</span>");
    }
}
```

If you put the extension method into a VS project and copy the DLL into the LINQPad plugins folder, it will be automatically available to all queries.

EDIT: You can now define that method in the 'My Extensions' query rather than having to create a project in VS.

Comment: The extensions class work wonderfully in LINQPad when I add it in my query, but compiling it to a separate DLL does not work. LINQPad is saying it doesn't have a definition for the extension. Perhaps there is something I missed when creating a class in VS. I don't want to take your time on this as I can wait for the final release with plugin baked in.

Comment: I presume you've checked the obvious things... the class is public and the namespace is imported (or more easily, you can define it the top-level namespace). Are you referencing the DLL manually from LINQPad or dropping it into the plugins folder?

Comment: Thank you for checking the obvious! I just didn't set the class public!! Oops. Thank you for your help and this great tip on enhancing the output.

Answer (score 3):

I have success with this code block in MyExtensions sketch:

```
void Main()
{
    (!(true.Dump())).Dump();
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool Dump (this bool value)
    {       
        string c = value ? "Blue" : "Red";
        Util.RawHtml ("<span style='color:" + c + "'>" + value + "</span>").Dump();
        return value;
    }
}
```